# when i add another php site ,this site was redirected to the other php site,i didn't write the redirect .conf file. what happend?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, server

when i add another nginx-php site,this site was redirected to another php site,i didn't write the redirect in .conf file. what happend?

[this is my new site](http://y2b.casvot.com/)   : y2b.casvot.com

[site above was redirected to this domain](https://www.casvot.com/)    : www.casvot.com

```
//=======================my nginx config file=================

    //
    //You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
    //of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
    //http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
    //http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
    //http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
    //Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
    //file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
    // Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
  // Default server configuration

    //================================================
    server {

        // SSL configuration
        //
        // listen 443 ssl default_server;
        //listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        // Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        // See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        // Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        //See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        //Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        //Don't use them in a production server!
        //include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /home/casvot;

        //Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
     // Index file path
        index index.php  index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name    casvot.com www.casvot.com;

        location / {
            //First attempt to serve request as file, then
            // as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        //pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

        location ~ \.php$ {               
            root /home/casvot/;            
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

            // With php7.0-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;         
        }

    //SSL configuration
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.casvot.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.casvot.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    }
    //Virtual Host configuration for example.com
    //
    // You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
    //to sites-enabled/ to enable it.

    server{

           listen 80;
           root /home/;
       index   index.php index.html index.htm ;
       server_name y2b.casvot.com;
         location / {
                    // First attempt to serve request as file, then
                    // as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            }

        location ~ \.php$ {

                      root /home;
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    // With php7.0-fpm:
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            }
    }
    server {
        if ($host = www.casvot.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } //managed by Certbot

        if ($host = casvot.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } // managed by Certbot

        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name casvot.com   www.casvot.com;
        return 404; //# managed by Certbot

    }
```

/home directory:

[image: /home]

Comment: WordPress keeps the domain name of where you installed it, in its database. You have to modify the database if you move the site.  Read the [WordPress Docs on _Moving a site_](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Comment: I mean i have already deploy a wordpress site(www.casvot.com), now i wanna  test another domain(use <?php phpinfo(); ?>),but this domain was redirect to www.casvot.com.

Comment: Please stop SHOUTING AT US and shouting things TWICE does not improve your chances of an answer either

Answer (score 0):

An issue doesn't stick out at me, but is it possible that your server and your ISP support IPv6? Maybe it's connecting via IPv6 and www.casvot.com is the only vhost listening. I don't see a `listen [::]:80;` for y2b.casvot.com, but I see it for the other.